# Android - Table Layout - Setting Background for Cells

Tags: android, cell, tablelayout

is there a way to achieve a drawable background for a cell in a table layout that has a button inside of it. The button already has its own background. i have a margin for the button in the cell that should not have the background of the row.
I want to visually differentiate the columns, so the cells with the buttons needs to be set to same background as the textviews above.

example pic:
[image]

regards marco

Comment: You can try putting the button in a layout that has the cell background and put this layout in the cell.

Comment: oh man. thanks, i was to blind to see this solution :) i just put the button in a linear layout and the whole thing as cell in the row.